# striping out the "content-type" from TIdMultiPartFormDataStream

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, delphi-xe8

This is kind of related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30254837/posting-a-file-as-part-of-a-form) post. I am trying to post some form data using `TIdHTTP` and `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream`, but when monitoring the communication using ***Wireshark***, each form field gets a `content-Type: text/plain` attached to it and for some reason the server that I am sending these stuff to does not like it. Is there a way that I can make sure only the name and value is sent?
The Content-Transfer was also being added and I was able to remove that using:

```
aFieldItem := PostStream.AddFormField(fName, fValue);
aFieldItem.ContentTransfer := '';
```

but I cannot find any way to get rid of content type.
At this moment the data that is being sent looke like this (in Wireshark)

```
Boundary: \r\n----------051715151353026\r\n
Encapsulated multipart part:  (text/plain)
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"\r\n
    Content-Type: text/plain\r\n
    Line-based text data: text/plain
        \r\n
        Testing new AW Mobile
```

and I want it to look like:

```
Boundary: \r\n------WebKitFormBoundary32hCBG8zkGMBpxqL\r\n
Encapsulated multipart part:
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"\r\n
    Data (21 bytes)
        Data: 0d0a5465737420616e6420747261636520636f6d6d
        Length: 21
```

Thank you
Sam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HTML5 Section 4.10.22.7](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/forms.html#multipart-form-data) alters how [RFC 2388](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388) applies to webform submissions:

> The parts of the generated multipart/form-data resource that correspond to **non-file fields must not have a Content-Type header specified**. Their names and values must be encoded using the character encoding selected above (field names in particular do not get converted to a 7-bit safe encoding as suggested in RFC 2388).

This is different from RFC 2388:

> As with all multipart MIME types, each part has an optional "Content-Type", which defaults to text/plain.

Your server is clearly expecting the HTML5 behavior.

The `Content-Type` header on each MIME part added to `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` <strike>is hard-coded and cannot be removed without altering `TIdMultipartFormDataStream`'s source code</strike> can be omitted by setting the `TIdFormDataField.ContentType` property to a space character (not a blank string, like the `ContentTransfer` property allows):

```
aFieldItem := PostStream.AddFormField(fName, fValue);
aFieldItem.ContentTransfer := '';
aFieldItem.ContentType := ' '; // <-- here
```

If you set the `ContentType` property to a blank string, it will set the `Content-Type` header to `application/octet-stream`, but assigning a space character instead has a side effect of omitting the header when the property setter parses the new value.

That being said, I have already made some changes to `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` to account for this change in webform submission in HTML5, but I have not finalized and released it yet.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestion as to how I can handle this in the meantime?

Comment: As I said, you would have to alter TIdMultipartFormDataStream's source code, and then recompile Indy.  Alternatively, copy its source code to a new unit/class in your project that you can then alter as needed. Or just write your own MIME data into a standard TStream, such as TMemoryStream.  I have no ETA on when the new TIdMultipartFormDataStream will be ready for release.

Comment: The 3rd option (MIME data into a standard TStream, such as TMemoryStream) sounds best. Do you have an example of doing that? I need to post a bunch of name-value pairs and a file and the end. Thanks

Comment: Actually I found an example [Here](http://forums2.atozed.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=14992) that made it work

Comment: Here is the discussion that talks about the changes needed to make `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` work with HTML5 servers: [Removing lines from TIdMultiPartFormDataStream](http://forums2.atozed.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=26683)

Comment: Thanks, this saved my day, I was going crazy because I could not send any plain form fields together with a file post.